# "Cannot find -I<library_name>" error during runtime

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-indigo, leptonica

Machine details :

```
64bit windows
MinGW installed
gcc version 4.8.1
make version 3.8.1
eclipse indigo CDT
```

I am trying to run a simple code using the image processing library leptonica.The code just reads an image and writes the image to a file.

```
int main() {
    PIX *new_pic = pixRead("C:\\Users\\random\\Downloads\\20140619_131838.jpeg");
    pixWrite("C:\\Users\\random\\Downloads\\20140619_.jpeg", new_pic, 0);
    return 1;
}
```

I have included all the libraries using the following procedure

```
Rightclick > Properties > c c++ general > libraries > Add > File System
```

I have also added the path to the libraries by clicking on the library path.There are about 14 libraries that i have added.The error that i am getting for each library is

```
Cannot find -I<path to library>
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?Is this the right way to include libraries?

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot find -I<path to library>
```

The -I directive is to specify additionals path for #include directives.
So you must specifi the path of the directory that contain all the headers (.h) files.

For the library part, you must do it in :

```
C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Libraries -> Add
```

Comment: The paths to header files have been added.The libraries have also been added using what you have said

Comment: Cannot find -I<path to library>
What is the exact message? does the path is a valid directory?

Comment: Yes it is a valid path to a .lib file that i have added in libraries -> Add

Comment: It must NOT be a path to a lib file. Just a path to a directory that dontains headers files.
You put the library files with the -l flag (gcc).
-I is for Inclue directory, and -l (and -L) is for linking Library files.